# Can I create an Azure aks kubernetes cluster using a centos image?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, centos, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create an Azure aks cluster using an centos image.

I have created an aks cluster with an ubuntu image.

Searched the internet and did not find anything to indicate that centos was an option.

```
    resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
       name       = "${var.aks_name}"
       location   = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
         dns_prefix = "${var.aks_dns_prefix}"

         resource_group_name =      "${data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"

        linux_profile {
           admin_username = "${var.vm_user_name}"

            ssh_key {
            key_data = "${file(var.public_ssh_key_path)}"
             }
           }

      addon_profile {
         http_application_routing {
         enabled = false
          }
        }

      agent_pool_profile {
          name            = "agentpool"
          count           = "${var.aks_agent_count}"
          vm_size         = "${var.aks_agent_vm_size}"
          os_type         = "Linux"
          os_disk_size_gb = "${var.aks_agent_os_disk_size}"
          vnet_subnet_id  = "${data.azurerm_subnet.kubesubnet.id}"
           }
```

Comment: Why you need centos? Kubernetes on ubuntu behaves absolutely the same.

Comment: We have hardened redhat images.  Have you ever needed to change/update the worker node configurations?

Comment: for that you cannot use AKS or any other managed Kubernetes. You have to install it and manage yourselves.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot control vm image used to create AKS. I think AKS-engine works with CoreOS. https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/issues/541

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't change that in Kubernetes managed services. Same applies for GKE and as I see it's the same in EKS.

It's AKS and you need to use custom images, in this case you would have to use cloud VM's in one of the cloud providers (I do not have experience with Azure so I can't say for sure but you can use [custom images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images) on AWS - [kops](https://medium.com/getamis/customize-aws-eks-worker-node-ami-d7b3d203051) and GCP). 
Also it is worth noting that in [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images?hl=en_US&_ga=2.259672458.-1629410743.1543233433) you can choose one of 3 node images:

- Container-Optimized OS from Google
- Container-Optimized OS with
  containerd (cos_containerd)
- Ubuntu

You mentioned that your main focus is security, so you might look closer to Container-Optimized OS from Google:

> The Container-Optimized OS node image is based on a recent version of
>   the Linux kernel and is optimized to enhance node security. It is
>   backed by a team at Google that can quickly patch it for security and
>   iterate on features. The Container-Optimized OS image provides better
>   support, security, and stability than other images.

You can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a prototype terraform plan which adds Centos Kubernetes workers (as VMSS) to a existing AKS. The protoype is of course opiniated and only supports a specific AKS configuration but it might be a base for other to implement custom workers nodes for AKS